# How do I unsubscribe from someone who signed me up for their updates from Find Me Spot?

Tags: spam-prevention

Somehow I have been added to people notified by email when someone named Theodore updates his status on Find Me Spot. Frustratingly there is no unsubscribe in the email and I can't find one when I click through to the site. Sending a [tweet to their Twitter account](http://www.twitter.com/#!/ahsteele/status/171637910758629377) didn't result in a reply.

Before I banish all emails from "noreply@findmespot.com" to my junk folder is there some mechanism to unsubscribe that I'm missing? Or is their service really this inconsiderate?

Here's the text of the email:

> noreply@findmespot.com  Theodore  Latitude:47.70228
>    Longitude:-122.17807  GPS location Date/Time:02/20/2012 18:41:35 MST
>
> Message:All is good !!
>
> Click the link below to see where I am located.
>   http://fms.ws/76-tS/47.70228N/122.17807W
>
> If the above link does not work, try this link:
>    47.70228,-122.17807
>
> Theodore
>
> You have received this message because Theodore has added you to
>   their SPOT contact list.
>
> Every day is an Adventure. Share Yours.  http://www.findmespot.com

Comment: Did you try [contacting the web site managers](http://www.findmespot.com/en/contactus/index.php)?

Comment: @AlE. I did years ago and haven't thought about this since that time.

Comment: What was the resolution? Can you add an answer?

Comment: @AlE. There is no answer never determined a way to do so. Sorry it's an unanswered question but it is reality.

Answer (score 1):

It seems these were not sent to harass you intentionally - just that there has been an error in entry of an e-mail address. The service is not free and up to date locations are relevant so 'Theodore' was probably missing out on what he had paid for while those emails were being sent to you.

Since so long ago I am not bothering to try to check with you but I would guess:

(a) you did eventually set up a redirection to junk, and
(b) there ceased to be a need for that a long time ago.

So probably of very little or no interest to anybody now but just in case something similar happens again (even if not between you and Theodore) one solution might be to contact Find Me Spot, for which [details](https://faq.findmespot.com/index.php?action=showEntry&data=391) are:

- e-mail at customerservice@findmespot.com, or
- toll-free phone at 866-OK1-SPOT (651-7768), or
- SPOT LLC, Attn: Customer Care, 461 p. Milpitas Blvd., Milpitas, CA, USA 95035.